# Nagios plugin check_logfiles postscript option cannot execute a postscript

Tags: perl, plugins, nagios

I'm working with a Nagios plugin called `check_logfiles`.  a pretty powerful script. I have it working on Unix/Linux and Windows.  well, all but 1 feature.  the ability to execute a post or pre script hook.

I just can't get a postscript to execute from the `check_logfiles.cfg`.

I get from `check_logfiles` protocol file
WARNING Errors in postscript (tag postscript)
cannot execute `custom_mail_alert.pl`

I tried running it with the `-d` trace option - no success gettng debug output. ?

I've tried several different implementations seen in config file below. Any help with understanding why a postscript cannot execute in `check_logfies` I really appreciate it much, thank you.

note: the script `check_logfiles` executes successfully even if postscript fails - this is OK and Good.
thank you for your help, I'm pulling my hair out :) I can't seem to figure it out.
check_logfiles works

- `custom_mail_alert.pl` works on command line, but not as called from `check_logfiles` ?
  The `check_logfiles.cfg`:

  ```
    $scriptpath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\contrib';
    $protocolsdir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\protocols';
    $seekfilesdir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\seek';

    $MACROS = {
    LOGS_DIR => 'C:\APMConnect\Logs',
    PP_INGESTION_EP => 'C:\APMConnect\AutoDataLoader\Scandir\ManageAPM',
    SRC_DIR => '\\win.alphper031.corporate.com\APM_Data_Storage\Zip File Archive',
    CL_CMAIL_SMTP_HOST => 'mail.ad.com',
    CL_CMAIL_TO => 'gary.l.mills@corp.com',
    CL_CMAIL_FROM => 'ALPCTS000000881@alpcts000000881.corp.com',
    CL_CMAIL_SUBJECT => 'APM Loader - Upload Failure Notification'
    };
    #$postscript = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\contrib\custom_mail_alert.pl';
    #$postscript = 'perl custom_mail_alert.pl';
    $postscript = 'custom_mail_alert.pl';
    $postscriptparams = '-Host $CL_CMAIL_SMTP_HOST$ -To $CL_CMAIL_TO$ -From $CL_CMAIL_FROM$ -Subject "$CL_CMAIL_SUBJECT$" -Body "The APM Loader Upload Failed.\n Please see attached." -Attachment "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\seek\check_logfiles.C__APMConnect_Logs_AutoLoader.log.504 Gateway Time-Out" -Send_if_rc_gt $CL_SERVICESTATEID$';

    #$postscriptstdin = '$CL_HOSTNAME$\t$CL_SERVICEDESC$\t$CL_SERVICESTATEID$\t$CL_SERVICEOUTPUT$\n';
    @searches = (
    {
    tag => '504 Gateway Time-Out',
    logfile => '$LOGS_DIR$\AutoLoader.log',
    rotation => 'AutoLoader.log.\d{1,2}',
    type => 'rotating',
    criticalpatterns => [
        '^java.lang.Exception:Method failed: HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Time-out Please check configuration details and replace or update the file :.*'],
        options => 'protocol,perfdata,script,supersmartscript',
        script => sub {
        use File::Copy;

    my $cmd = 'net use E: /delete /y';
    my $other_cmd = 'net use E: \\\\win.alphper031.corporate.com\\APM_Data_Storage /USER:logon.ds.com\\lg4274sv xnEDs7UMh3gT /PERSISTENT:YES';

    my $other_status = system($other_cmd);

    my $_source_dir = $ENV{CHECK_LOGFILES_SRC_DIR};
    my $_target_dir = $ENV{CHECK_LOGFILES_PP_INGESTION_EP};
    my $sout = $ENV{CHECK_LOGFILES_SERVICEOUTPUT};
    my $result = rindex($sout, 'FaultData');
    my $_file_name = substr($sout, $result, length($sout));

    opendir (dir, $_source_dir);

    if( -f "$_source_dir/$_file_name" ) {
        copy ("$_source_dir\\$_file_name", "$_target_dir\\$_file_name");
        if ( $? ) {
            printf 'OK - File Copy Successful!';
            printf " Copied File to Refeed APM: $_source_dir\\$_file_name";
            return 0;
        } else {
            printf 'CRITICAL - File Copy Failed!';
            printf " - Source dir: $_source_dir\\$_file_name";
            return 2;
        }
    } else {
        printf 'CRITICAL - File Copy Failed, File CANNOT be located! Resource may not be Mounted!';
        printf " - Source dir: $_source_dir\\$_file_name";
        return 2;
    }
    closedir($dir); 
     }});
  ```

The `custom_mail_alert.pl` script:

```
! C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $Host;
my $To;
my $From;
my $Subject;
my $Body;
my $Attachment;
my $Send_if_rc_gt;
GetOptions(
"Host=s" => \$Host,
"To=s" => \$To,
"From=s" => \$From,
"Subject=s" => \$Subject,
"Body=s" => \$Body,
"Attachment=s" => \$Attachment,
"Send_if_rc_gt=i" => \$Send_if_rc_gt
);

printf "host:$Host\n";
printf "to:$To\n";
printf "from:$From\n";
printf "subject:$Subject\n";
printf "body:$Body\n";
printf "attachment:$Attachment\n";
printf "send_if_rc_gt:$Send_if_rc_gt\n";

my @cmd = ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Nagios\NCPA\contrib\cmail.exe');
push @cmd, "-host:$Host";
push @cmd, "-to:$To";
push @cmd, "-from:$From";
push @cmd, "-subject:$Subject";
push @cmd, "-body:$Body";
push @cmd, "-a:$Attachment";

printf "@cmd\n";

if (!defined $Host||!defined $To||!defined $From||!defined $Subject ||!defined $Body){
print "Usage: $0 -Host <host> -To <to> -From <from> -Subject <subject> -Body <mail body=""> -Attachment [--send-if-rc-gt <1-9> ]\n";
exit (-1);
}
require $Attachment;</mail></subject></from></to></host>

if ((defined $state->{'servicestateid'} && defined $Send_if_rc_gt) && ($state->{'servicestateid'} > $Send_if_rc_gt)){
print "$state->{'servicestateid'} was lower than $send_if_rc_gt\n";
exit 0;
}
if ($state->{'serviceoutput'}){
system(@cmd);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but looks like the `#` is missing from the shebang in `custom_mail_alert.pl` Try change the first line to `#! C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl -w`

Comment: geese, sorry Hakon, cut and paste error.  thank you